# Excel VBA VLookup - Error 13 - "Type Mismatch"

Tags: vba, excel, vlookup

I am working on a Excel VBA Macro that gets the email of a client from another sheet.

I am getting Error 13 "Type Mismatch" from the VLookup:

```
For Each c In Range("D3:D130").Cells

    If c > 500 Then

      Dim emailadress As String
      Dim client_name As String
      Dim lookup_mail As Range

      Set lookup_mail = Sheets("MAILS").Range("A1:D130")

      client_name = Range("A" & (c.Row)).Value

      emailadress = Application.VLookup(client_name, lookup_mail, 4, False)
```

If I make it this way it works just fine:

```
      emailadress = Application.VLookup("John Doe", lookup_mail, 4, False)
```

So I guess there is something is wrong with the way I "declare?" client_name. Which is strange because when I output client_name in a MsgBox it pops up perfectly.

(I use VBA beacause I need to send automatic emails to clients)

Any help apreciated!

Comment: A Type 13 error at that point typically indicates that the value could not be found. Have you debugged and what is the value of `client_name` at the point of the error? Run `Debug.Print char(39) & client_name & chr(39)` just before the vlookup and check the Immediate window to see if there are leading/trailing spaces in the source and/or the target.

Comment: The value is correct, I get the client name, but the VLookup for some reason fails to read that value...

Comment: Shouldn't it be `Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(...)`? Also if you named the Range("A1:D130"), you could just put the text in VLookup, you can also make this named range dynamic so you don't worry about the size of the range changes.

Comment: What's the purpose of `If c > 500 Then`? Do you mean the value in c (`c.Value`)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My guess is, it is not your VLOOKUP that is raising the type mismatch error, but assigning its return value to a string. Your VLOOKUP might be trying to assign an error value to a string, and that gives a type mismatch. Try using a variant instead.

Also, declaring variables inside a loop burns my eyes. Same goes to everything you can actually do OUTSIDE the loop, like setting the lookup_mail range - it is good practice to do as little inside a loop as possible for optimization purposes.

```
Dim emailadress As Variant
Dim client_name As String
Dim lookup_mail As Range
Dim c As Range

Set lookup_mail = Sheets("MAILS").Range("A1:B3")

For Each c In Range("D3:D130").Cells
  If c.Value > 500 Then
    client_name = Range("A" & (c.Row)).Value
    emailadress = Application.VLookup(client_name, lookup_mail, 4, False)
  End If
Next
```

This way your code will work, but your emailadress variable might contain an error. Check that.

EDIT:

If you use application.worksheetfunction.vlookup, it might work better. If Vlookup raises an error, it just gives back an error in VBA, and is not trying to return it to a variable.

Comment: Thanks, I got a step further. Sorry about the variables inside the loop hehe. So what should I do now? emailadress is returning error 2024 as a result.

Comment: "declaring variables inside a loop burns my eyes" ... why? `Dim` statements aren't executed inside a loop.

Comment: @BigBen Because whatever you can do outside a loop you should do outside a loop. Optimization. I know that this practically changes nothing in VBA, but I still think it is a bad habit. I never said it was wrong, I just said it burned my eyes. :) But you are right, I'll update the emphasis and the reasoning.

Comment: Perhaps helpful reference: `Dim` statements [aren't executed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6139818/when-is-a-dim-statement-processed-when-vba-code-is-compiled) inside a loop. You're not optimizing by moving them outside. 100% agree with the `Set` outside the loop though.

Answer (score 1):

You can try out this, it may work if your range or value comes from a database with poor string or number formatting:

```
emailadress = Application.VLookup(WorksheetFunction.Text(client_name), lookup_mail, 4, False)
```

Cheers,

Pascal

http://multiskillz.tekcities.com