# Excel VBA Vlook up in Named Table

Tags: excel, vba

I have a named table in an excel worksheet which I have assigned to a `ListObject` for easy access and then assigned to the correct table.

```
dim looktbl as list object
Set looktbl = Worksheets("AI").ListObjects("ActionItems")
```

I'm then trying to use it as part of a `vlookup` call to correlate the header value of a column to the correct action item in my table. The table is arranged as numerical values 1...19 in A and then related text in `column B`. But this gives me an error:

```
Dim AItext as String
AItext = Application.VLookup(tbl.HeaderRowRange(1, cCnt), looktbl.DataBodyRange, 2, False)
```

When I run this I get `Run-time Error '13': Type mismatch`

I've verified that `tbl.HeaderRowRange(1, cCnt)` is the header value with `debug.print`. I'm certain that it's the looktbl part of this that is broken but I'm not sure exactly how it should look.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Excel VBA VLookup - Error 13 - "Type Mismatch"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31733198/excel-vba-vlookup-error-13-type-mismatch)  As suggested in the answer there, try `Dim AItext as Variant` to catch both string returns as well as error type returns.

Comment: "I've verified that tbl.HeaderRowRange(1, cCnt) is the header value with debug.print" - so `tbl.HeaderRowRange(1, cCnt)` is a number between 1 and 19 (i.e. one of the values in the first column of `looktbl.DataBodyRange`)?