# Initializing an indefinite number of classes in VBA: Using variable to name instance of class

Tags: vba, class, excel

As always, this may be something of a newb question but here goes:

I have a Class with 15 properties. Each class represents information about an item of stock (how many there are, how many recently shipped etc). Each time a class is initialized by passing it a stock code, it gathers all the data from other sources and stores it as properties of the class.

I want to be able to initialize *n* number of classes, dependent on the length of a list (never more than 200). I want to name those classes by their stock code, so that I can call up the information later on and add to it. The only problem is I don't know how to use a variable to name a class. I don't really want to write out 200 classes long hand because I'm sure there is a better way to do it than `Dim`ing: `Stock1 As C_ICODE, Stock2 As C_ICODE, Stock3 As C_ICODE` etc and initializing them in order, until input (from `ActiveCell`) `= ""` or it hits the maximum list length of 200. I would like to create as many class instances as there are stock codes if possible, and generate them something like this:

PseudoCode:

```
For Each xlCell In xlRange
    strIN = xlCell.Value

    Dim ICode(strIN) As New C_ICODE

    ICode(strIN).lIcode = strIN
Next
```

`Let`ting `classname.lIcode = strIN` provides the class with all the user input it needs and then it carries out various functions and subroutines to get the other 14 properties.

I would be very grateful if someone could let me know if this sort of thing is possible in VBA, and if so, how I could go about it? Definitely struggling to find relevant information.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [Dictionary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x4k5wbx4%28v=vs.84%29.aspx) object:

```
Dim ICode As Object
Set ICode = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

For Each xlCell In xlRange
    strIN = xlCell.Value

    ICode.Add strIN, New C_ICODE

    ICode(strIN).lIcode = strIN
Next
```

Comment: +1 You could also use a `Collection`, which would avoid the need for a `CreateObject`.

Comment: @DougGlancy You can add a reference to `Microsoft Scripting Runtime` in **Tools -> References ...** and using `Dim ICode As New Dictionary`; that would also avoid `CreateObject`. There are other benefits of using a Dictionary over a Collection, for example retrieving the list of keys.

Comment: This will crash if the stock code appears in two different cells. But that might be a good thing.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with CreateObject. Don't use Dim x as new x, see here for details: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2478097/vba-difference-in-two-ways-of-declaring-a-new-object-trying-to-understand-why. Finally, you can Dim ICode as Scripting.Dictionary.

Answer (score 2):

I just did a quick test of this and it seems as though it might work for you.  You can create an array to hold multiple instances of your class.

```
Sub thing()

    Dim cArray(1 To 10) As Class1
    Dim x As Long

    For x = 1 To UBound(cArray)
        Set cArray(x) = New Class1
    Next

    ' Assume the class has a property Let/Get for SomeProperty:
    For x = 1 To UBound(cArray)
        cArray(x).SomeProperty = x * 10
    Next

    For x = 1 To UBound(cArray)
        Debug.Print cArray(x).SomeProperty
    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Also very interesting. It was something I thought must be possible, but wasn't sure about