# Adding Objects to a collection in VBA --> OOP-Basics?

Tags: vba, oop, excel

I am new to OOP, so probably there is an obvious explaination why this does not work. I am trying to add objects to a collection in VBA. 
My class module is this:

```
Option Explicit

'the person class
Public FirstName As String
Public LastName As String

Property Get FullName() As String
  'return the person's full name
  FullName = FirstName & " " & LastName
End Property
```

My Code is this:

```
Sub myProg()


'create a new collection!
Dim Persons As New Collection

Dim p1 As New clsPerson

'give them names in "Loop"

p1.FirstName = "Rita"
p1.LastName = "Smith"
Persons.Add p1

p1.FirstName = "Sue"
p1.LastName = "Jones"
Persons.Add p1

p1.FirstName = "Bob"
p1.LastName = "Brown"
Persons.Add p1

'"Loop" end

For Each p1 In Persons
  Debug.Print p1.FullName
Next p1

End Sub
```

It returns 3 times "Bob Brown". I would like it to return the 3 names I entered.

Comment: Just curios but could this be achieved the same using an array of clsPerson's?

Comment: Btw, dont use `Dim ... as New ...`. It is [**evil**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2478097/vba-difference-in-two-ways-of-declaring-a-new-object-trying-to-understand-why)..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`p1` is a reference variable, it points to the single specific instance of `clsPerson` you created when you used `New`.

When you add a reference variable to a collection you are adding the reference itself, not a copy, meaning the `p1` in the collection is always going to be pointing to the same `clsPerson` instance which will contains the last values you assigned to it.

You need to use `New` to create a new, independent instance of the class and add that to the collection, E.g.

```
Set p1 = New clsPerson
p1.FirstName = "Bob"
p1.LastName = "Brown"
Persons.Add p1

Set p1 = New clsPerson
p1.FirstName = "Sue"
p1.LastName = "Jones"
Persons.Add p1
```

Comment: The first sentence is not true for the OP's code. `Dim ... As New` is declaration and not instantiation in `VBA`. [The variable is instantiating when it is first found in the code](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/classes.aspx).

Comment: That's a plumbing detail that does not affect this scenario

Answer (score 1):

When you alter p1 the 2nd and 3rd time you're altering the reference at each spot in the collection.  The collection hold a reference to p1 and that reference can be altered externally from the collection itself.  You need to make three person objects.

```
Sub myProg()
    'create a new collection!
    Dim Persons As Collection

    Dim p1 As clsPerson
    Dim p2 As clsPerson
    Dim p3 As clsPerson
    Dim p As clsPerson

    'give them names in "Loop"

    set Persons = New Collection
    set p1 = new clsPerson
    p1.FirstName = "Rita"
    p1.LastName = "Smith"
    Persons.Add p1

    set p2 = new clsPerson        
    p2.FirstName = "Sue"
    p2.LastName = "Jones"
    Persons.Add p2

    set p3 = new clsPerson        
    p3.FirstName = "Bob"
    p3.LastName = "Brown"
    Persons.Add p3

    '"Loop" end

    For Each p In Persons
      Debug.Print p.FullName
    Next p

    'alternate looping way where a new object is created each time
    For i = 1 To 5
        Set p = New clsPerson
        p.FirstName = "First Name" & i
        p.LastName = "Last Name" & i
        Persons.Add p
        Set p = Nothing 'may not be necessary
    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: in my case, I have a real loop, with 100+ cycles, so creating variables would be impossible. Thanks anyway, Made things clearer!

Comment: Okay, I forgot to mention it in my text but I did add a looping structure to the end of the code.  It's similar to your accepted answer in loop form.

Answer (score 0):

Just **don't REuse `p1` in the `For Each`** and this will do it ;)

```
Sub myProg()


'create a new collection!
Dim Persons As New Collection

Dim p1 As New clsPerson
Dim pT As clsPerson

'give them names in "Loop"

p1.FirstName = "Rita"
p1.LastName = "Smith"
Persons.Add p1

p1.FirstName = "Sue"
p1.LastName = "Jones"
Persons.Add p1

p1.FirstName = "Bob"
p1.LastName = "Brown"
Persons.Add p1

'"Loop" end

For Each pT In Persons
  Debug.Print pT.FullName
Next pT

End Sub
```