# How to destroy an object

Tags: excel, ms-access, vb6, vba

It seems that `Set Object = Nothing` didn't destroy the `Fs` Object in this code:

```
Sub Test2()
    Dim Fs As New FileSystemObject
    Set Fs = Nothing
    MsgBox Fs.Drives.Count ' this line works
End Sub
```

The last line works with no errors!. thats mean `Fs` Object is still exists, right?.

So how to destroy this `Fs` Object.

Comment: Let it go out of scope?  Why do you feel a need to destroy it?

Comment: @Comintern, I use this object to read an write to text file saved in TrueCrypt volume, and after using it I can't dismount this volume, maybe if I destroy it I can dismount this volume.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [VBA: Difference in two ways of declaring a new object? (Trying to understand why my solution works)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2478097/vba-difference-in-two-ways-of-declaring-a-new-object-trying-to-understand-why)

Comment: That sounds like an issue with whatever code you're using to read and write the text file.  The code above won't hold an FSO reference after it completes.

Comment: @Comintern in some sense a duplicate, but someone who didn't know the answer to the question wouldn't even suspect that it is a duplicate and wouldn't know how to search for it.

Comment: @Mat'sMug, I was eagerly waiting for your explanation. Cannot say I got it though. But I've got something to think over for a while...

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Another way to ensure proper destruction of an object, is to yield its object reference to a `With` block (i.e. don't declare a local variable):

```
Sub Test()
    With New FileSystemObject
        MsgBox .Drives.Count
    End With
End Sub
```

The object only ever exists inside the `With` block, and when execution reaches the `End With` token, if you try it with a custom class module you'll notice that the the class' `Class_Terminate` handler runs, effectively confirming the proper destruction of the object.

As for the `As New` quirk, [as was already explained](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42164925/1188513), if you intend to set the object reference to `Nothing` inside that scope, don't declare it with `As New`, because VBA *will* set the object reference to `Nothing`, but will also happily ("helpfully") create a new instance for you as soon as you re-reference it again, be it only to verify that the object `Is Nothing`.

Side note, this (annoying) counter-intuitive behavior is specifically what's behind the reasoning for [**Rubberduck**](http://rubberduckvba.com)'s *Object variable is self-assigned* code inspection:

[image: RD website's inspection results]

<sub>(note: if you've got code you want to inspect, know that it runs **much** faster in the actual VBE than on the website)</sub>

(if it wasn't clear already: I'm heavily involved with the Rubberduck project)

Comment: Thank a lot @Mat's Mug. user3598756 and Zerk answers are great and help me, but I think your answer is the best and should be the accepted answer to help other users too.

Comment: Hmm, I didn't mean to steal a checkmark here, only to provide *additional* information - thanks anyway!

Comment: I was know about `Dim` then `Set` and test it before I post my question, but I was looking for additional information like your answer, Thank you again.

Answer (score 20):

it must have to do with the "declare & instantiate" pattern, most often addressed as a "to be avoided" pattern

if you split them, you get `Nothing` after setting it to:

```
Sub Test2()
    Dim Fs As FileSystemObject
    Set Fs = New FileSystemObject
    Set Fs = Nothing
    MsgBox Fs.Drives.Count ' this line DOESN'T work
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks a lot user3598756, and i'm sorry but I think @Mat's Mug  posts a great answer.

Answer (score 12):

This amended code seems to work fine. Seems a nuance with the dim/new on the same line. Hopefully someone else can give a better idea as to the reasoning.

As others have commented, if it is a dim within the sub then it will be collected after the sub completes anyway.

```
Sub Test2()
    Dim Fs As FileSystemObject
    Set Fs = New FileSystemObject
    Set Fs = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: I had the same issue with a collection that wasn't clearing after code finished running. I had declared at the top of my module like this: Dim coll As New Collection. I removed the New keyword then added this inside my sub: Set Coll = New Collection. I tried different methods like = nothing but this was the only thing that worked.

Comment: @SendETHToThisAddress, if you had put this as an answer, I'd upvote it. That's what worked for me, as well.