# Close Shell.Application Instance

Tags: vba, windows-shell

I'm writing a script to open documents using the default program via the Windows shell based on [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18921168/how-can-excel-vba-open-file-using-default-application):

```
Dim Shex As Object
Set Shex = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
tgtfile = "C:\Nax\dud.txt"
Shex.Open (tgtfile)
```

I notice the instance of `Shell.Application` never gets closed. In my code, I `Set Shex = Nothing`, but is that enough? If I create a Word or Outlook instance, for example, I would need to close it with `.Quit` before setting the variable to nothing. There's nothing obviously analogous going on here.

I set a reference to `Microsoft Shell Controls and Automation` to explore the `Shell` object, but couldn't find any methods for the `.Application` or `.Parent` properties, let alone one that looked like `.Quit`.

Am I missing something obvious? Does the garbage collector somehow also get rid of the instance? Is it something specific to the shell object itself?

Comment: I don't think you really instance an application; the object created in VBA just allows you the same access you'd get from a Shell GUI to the same file/folder heirarchy, so once the object is set to nothing it's gone.

Comment: Or to put it another way, you're only instancing a class which gives you an interface to access this, that and the other, but not an actual stand-alone application.

Comment: You may find this discussion helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42164719/how-to-destroy-an-object  . One suggestion is to limit the scope of the object's existence by framing it within a "with" statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thinking about it, I'm pretty sure @jamheadart is right and I'm just instancing a VBA class rather than creating an application class in Windows.

To be sure, though, I'm taking @Mert Y's suggestion of using a context manager to limit scope.

Final code:

```
With CreateObject("Shell.Application")
    .Open (strPath)
End With
```