# Setting variable to the next instance in the list does not work

Tags: vba, excel, linked-list

Context: I'm coding the *Dijkstra's Shortest Path Algorithm* just to practice basic patterns I've read on tutorials about [excel-vba](/questions/tagged/excel-vba).

I ran into a problematic situation. After long time debugging I found the issue.

Here is a minified version which shows the problem (commented):

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub btnSolution_Click()
    Dim N As Integer: N = 3

    'Creating one list with the first cell as head
    Dim list As New model_linked_list
    Set list.next_cell = Nothing

    'Creates list 1..N
    Dim i As Integer: i = N
    Do While i > 0
        'Creates the next cell adding to the start (after the head-cell)
        Dim cell As New model_linked_list
        cell.city = i
        Set cell.next_cell = list.next_cell

        'Update head-cell
        Set list.next_cell = cell
        i = i - 1
    Loop

    'All good till here, but when I try to loop over the list:

    Dim item As model_linked_list
    Set item = list.next_cell

    'You will to set a breakpoint in this line to avoid infinite loop
    Do While Not item Is Nothing

        MsgBox item.city 'Always shows "1"

        'This is the problematic line
        Set item = item.next_cell 'It seems like it does nothing, literally
    Loop

End Sub
```

[image]

My `model_linked_list` is just:

```
Option Explicit

Public city As Integer
Public next_cell As model_linked_list
```

Illustrating, the above code should just create one list like this:

[image]

It seems like `Set` is just not working when I try to go to the next cell in the list. Have anyone seen this before? How to work around it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should create a `New` copy of `Cell` each time you loop through the first loop, so `Set Cell = New model_linked_list`.  At the moment you are just updating the one instance.  (Remember that `Dim` statements are only done at the start of the subroutine, no matter where they are located in the code.)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [VBA: Difference in two ways of declaring a new object? (Trying to understand why my solution works)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2478097/vba-difference-in-two-ways-of-declaring-a-new-object-trying-to-understand-why)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your mistake is here:

> ```
> Dim cell As New model_linked_list
> ```

change it into:

```
Dim cell As model_linked_list
Set cell = New model_linked_list
```

In short, with `Dim cell As New model_linked_list`, the *"New"* operator was executed only once, so you were manipulating the same object in all your iterations.

Comment: My comment beat your answer by about 20 seconds (but I didn't have to make my comment look pretty) :D

Comment: @YowE3K Dóh, why do you hate writing answers?? :D In fact I was considering writing just a correction but then thought it is worth adding some explanation. I feel OP comes from some C++ background.

Comment: Because I had this vague feeling that the question would be marked as a duplicate anyway - I know there have been lots of times where I have seen people being told not to use the `Dim x As New y` structure.  (If I could just **remember** one of those cases, I would mark it as duplicate myself! :D  P.S.  I just googled `site:stackoverflow.com excel-vba dim as new` and found the appropriate dup.)

Comment: @YowE3K Instead of googling I was following the code and testing it. OP provided a nice MCVE and the question has its own flavor even if at the end the same error that we found occured in another thread. `Dijkstra` (particularly attractive to me), linked list, class etc... :)

Comment: Thank you guys... I learned something new with it, and my code is working perfectly now :)

Comment: I actually upvoted the question, even though it is a dup - it does provide a good landing point for people searching for this issue.